# Fetching product url and remove product from cart

Tags: product, cart, magento-1, url

The following is code

```
$itemsCollection = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {

    echo '<div class="qc-row qc-row-item">';
    echo '<span class="qc-col-qty">'.$item->getQty().'</span>';
    echo '<span class="qc-col-name"><a href="'.$item->getUrl().'">'.$item->getName().'</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="qc-col-price">'.$item->getPrice().'</span>';
    echo '<span class="qc-col-price">'.$item->getRemoveUrl().'</span>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Everything is fine but `'.$item->getUrl().'` and `'.$item->getRemoveUrl().'` are not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get cart item remove url by using $item->getRemoveUrl()and product URL from

Because magento  doesn't save remove and product url.

so please try this

### cart remove url

```
$itemRemoveUrl=$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('id'=>$item->getId(),
   Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED=>$this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl())
        );
```

### Product Url: By Item product object

```
 $product = $item->getProduct();
 $productUrl=$product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
```

### Your code

```
       foreach($items as $item) {

    echo '<div class="qc-row qc-row-item">';
    echo '<span class="qc-col-qty">'.$item->getQty().'</span>';

    $itememoveUrl=$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete',array('id'=>$item->getId(),
                Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl())
        );
 $product = $item->getProduct();
 $productUrl=$product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);

    echo '<span class="qc-col-name"><a href="'.$productUrl.'">'.$item->getName().'</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="qc-col-price">'.$item->getPrice().'</span>';
    echo '<span class="qc-col-remove"><a href="'.$itememoveUrl.'"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a></span>';
    echo '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: Not working.. Can you update my above given code and paste here so that I can fully copy paste. Will it get repeats even if the customer adds 6 different items?

Comment: update and it works